# Entity Framework Core support for SQL Spatial Data Types - DBGeography?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to make a web application using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages that has some geographic data in SQL Server.  Visual Studio gives an error that it doesn't support the Geography data type when creating the EF model using EF Core from an existing SQL DB.  Is there a way to use SQL Spatial Data Types like Geography in an ASP.NET Core project using Entity Framework or EF Core?

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1100) link shows some workarounds but nothing out of the box.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908803/how-to-use-sqlserver-types-spatial-types-within-asp-net-core-1-0-application) is an older post dealing with this question.

Comment: No, there's no support for Entity Framework Core. You will need to use Entity Framework 6 (which you can in ASP.NET Core if you target .NET Framework)

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728227/system-data-entity-spatial-replacement-in-asp-net-core. EF Core still not supporting spatial type yet; you need to use `Microsoft.Spatial` or `System.Spatial` to do so.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Does EF6 work seamlessly with ASP.NET Core if targeting .NET Framework?  In doing that can you still deploy ASP.NET Core on other platforms with docker?

Comment: No, because you need to target .NET Framework (i.e Windows only)

Answer (score 23):

Spatial data support is introduced with the version 2.2 of Entity Framework Core. It uses [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) data types and maps them to `geography` or `geometry` SQL Server types.
You can install NetTopologySuite via NuGet:

```
Install-Package NetTopologySuite
```

And you will also need the following NuGet package for EF Core spatial data support for SQL Server:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
```

and to use the `UseNetTopologySuite` option in your EF context configuration:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        @"my connection string",
        x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var nearestCity = db.Cities
    .OrderBy(c => c.Location.Distance(currentLocation))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I wrote about it in my [Finding Nearby Users with Entity Framework Core Spatial Data](https://www.markopapic.com/finding-nearby-users-using-ef-core-spatial-data.html) blog post.

Comment: did you mean Install-Package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite` ?

Comment: Your blog link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across your post and also the first link you mentioned. Only a few days ago, a preview version of EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.0 was published which is supposed to support spatial data types in SQL Server.

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1100#issuecomment-417618315 and the following comments.

I haven't tried it myself yet and it's probably not working 100%, but it's surely worth a try.