# EF Core 3.1 The property 'Geometry.UserData' could not be mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, spatial

I have a database-first .net core 3.1 web application which connects to SQL Server database table with a `geography` column. The database scaffolding and application build completes without any issue however when I run the application I get an error. If I add the `[NotMapped]` attribute the error is gone but obviously the property is not mapped. What could be the issue?

> The property 'Geometry.UserData' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'object' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

I have installed these packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v3.1.8
- NetTopologySuite.Core v1.15.3

The scaffolded class look like this

```
public class MyClass
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry Location { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: You are trying to add `Object<T>` to database, maybe instead shouldn't you use a foreign key with the `Object<T>` as its own table?

Comment: Please add table schema into the question.

Comment: @janzen the class is scaffolded directly from the database using the ef tool. There is no manual intervention. This is why I am asking the question, since all other tables / properties are scaffolded correctly and can be saved/retrieved from db.

Comment: @MortezaAsadi the table schema is exactly the same as MyClass with the exception of Location field which type is set to `geography`

Comment: [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681889/entity-framework-core-support-for-sql-spatial-data-types-dbgeography), maybe helpful

Comment: @MortezaAsadi i have seen this post. If you see in the question i am using exactly the same libraries, however i cannot pass this error.

Comment: Did you add UseNetTopologySuite in the OnConfiguring method?

Comment: @MortezaAsadi yes this line is added in the scaffolded datacontext  see below (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
            }

Answer (score 17):

I have found an answer which is a combination of several things. First, after installing the necessary Topology packages re-run the database ef scaffolding. Then, in Startup.cs add `.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString, x=> x.UseNetTopologySuite();`. Bear in mind that the generated Datacontext also includes the same line, but it is not excecuted since it is written within `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

After updating NetTopologySuite 5 to 6 it worked for me

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sqlOption =>
            sqlOption.UseNetTopologySuite()
         ));




 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="6.0.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.4">
```

Answer (score 2):

Heads up on this. Doing the following alone won't resolve the issue:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    // already configured for ASP.NET Core
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=LouisHowe"
            , x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            //.LogTo(Debug.WriteLine); 
    }
}
```

You **also** need to put it in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<TrackingDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LouisHoweDb"),
x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()));
```

Comment: Since I set my connection string during the runtime, I actually did need it in the OnConfiguring.

Comment: @wilsjd I updated my answer to say put it in both - thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a `DesignTimeDbContextFactory` which caught me off guard when trying to create migrations. I had correctly configured `Program.cs` but forgot about the design time factory, here is the code...

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace YourNamespace;

public class YourDbContextDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>
{
    public YourDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        => new(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>()
              .UseSqlServer("Server=YourServer;Database=YourDatabase;", 
               x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()).Options);
}
```